# MacVim Python Indentation Issue

Tags: python, vim

For the past 6 hours, I have been trying to find the source of an annoying bug in my MacVim setup. For reasons detailed below, the first time I opened up a Python file, the indentation was set correctly from the file `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim`, which for me was `/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-72/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/ftplugin`.

However on every subsequent Python file load, the `shiftwidth` reverted to the global default of 2, which I have set in my `.vimrc`. In tracking down the issue, I finally came upon this code in the `$VIMRUNTIME/ftpluin/python.vim` file:

```
if exists('*<SID>Python_jump') | finish | endif

fun! <SID>Python_jump(motion) range
    let cnt = v:count1
    let save = @/    " save last search pattern
    mark '
    while cnt > 0
        silent! exe a:motion
        let cnt = cnt - 1
    endwhile
    call histdel('/', -1)
    let @/ = save    " restore last search pattern
endfun

if has("gui_win32") && !exists("b:browsefilter")
    let b:browsefilter = "Python Files (*.py)\t*.py\n" .
                       \ "All Files (*.*)\t*.*\n"
endif

" As suggested by PEP8.
setlocal expandtab shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 tabstop=8
```

On the first load, `<SID>Python_jump` isn't defined, so the PEP8 style indentation settings are applied. However, on every next load, the function is available and so the `shiftwidth` settings are never applied. If I comment out the `if exists('*<SID>Python_jump') | finish | endif` line, it works as expected and the indentation settings are set correctly on every file load.

Now, what I'm wondering is if this is a genuine problem faced by others as well; in which case I should probably fix it and open up a pull request on the MacVim repo, or do I have something else wrong? I have tried disabling every plugin (I use Vundle, so I just commented out their `Bundle` lines in my `.vimrc`), but the result is the same.

**Edit**
 As pointed out by krystah, a `au FileType python set shiftwidth=4` also fixes the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue. Putting the following line in `.vimrc` fixed it though.
`au FileType python set shiftwidth=4`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention it in the question, but the same thing fixes it for me as well. However, what I'm curious about is if it is an actual issue in MacVim or just something we have wrong in our installations. Thanks!

Comment: I just tried with a separate MacVim installation (the Homebrew one) and the bug appears to be present there as well. Not really the first time Vim comes buggy out of the box, though :)

Comment: This is not specific to MacVim; command line Vim uses the same files. The `setlocal expandtab ...` should indeed go with the other `setlocal` commands, and not below that `if exists` check.

Comment: You should send a bug report to the vim-dev mailing list or directly to the script's maintainer.